Is there anything like a Čech complex for calculating local cohomology over *noncommutative* rings?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}\DeclareMathOperator\colim{colim}$Let $R$ be a ring, and consider a two-sided ideal $I = (r_1, r_2, \dots, r_j)$ in $R$. The corresponding $n$th local cohomology functor is defined as the $n$th right derived functor of the functor $H^0_I: \Mod(R) \rightarrow \Mod(R)$ given by $H^0_I(M) = \colim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \hom_R(R/I^n, M)$.
Sometimes you need to calculate local cohomology groups in cases where you can't get very far using the definition along with standard generalities about right derived functors (Grothendieck spectral sequences etc.). If $R$ is also assumed to be commutative, then you get great mileage from using the Čech complex to calculate $H^*_I(M)$. The Čech complex is defined as a colimit of Koszul complexes, as follows. For each element $a\in R$, let $K_a^{\bullet}$ be the cochain complex given by a copy of $R$ in degree $0$, another copy of $R$ in degree $1$, and the differential $R\rightarrow R$ is multiplication by $a$. The Čech complex $C^{\bullet}_I$ is the colimit of the tensor products of the Koszul complexes for the various powers of the generators $r_1, \dots ,r_j$ of the ideal $I$: $C^{\bullet}_I = \colim_{i_1, \dots ,i_j\rightarrow \infty} K_{r_1^{i_1}}^{\bullet} \otimes_R \dotsb \otimes_R K_{r_j^{i_j}}^{\bullet}$. In that colimit, you have to be using the correct maps between the complexes: in particular, your map does something different on the $1$-cochains in each tensor factor $K_r^{\bullet}$ than on the $0$-cochains. Details are in Greenlees–May's 1992 paper "Derived functors of $l$-adic completion and local homology," for example.
The point is that, under mild assumptions on $R$, including commutativity, you can calculate $H^*_I(M)$ by taking the cohomology of $C^{\bullet}_I \otimes_R M$. This is an old idea: I learned it from Greenlees–May, but they cite Hartshorne's little 1967 book "Local Cohomology," and Hartshorne cites Serre's 1958 "Algèbre locale." Different people seem to have different names for the various complexes: for example, I have seen some authors also use the name "Koszul complex" for what I have called the "Čech complex."
However, the usefulness of the Čech complex for calculating local cohomology apparently hinges on the ring $R$ being commutative. The definition of local cohomology, as a right derived functor, still makes sense for noncommutative $R$. I have read a large number of papers about the noncommutative case of local cohomology. But I have found no mention of a Čech-like complex for calculating local cohomology over noncommutative rings. (I mean really noncommutative, i.e., not just the graded-commutative case where $xy$ agrees with $yx$ up to sign.) I don't see a way to make the idea work without commutativity of $R$.
Here is my question: is there a small and explicitly-calculable complex, like the Čech complex, which yields local cohomology in the noncommutative case? As far as I know, the answer is no, but I hope I am mistaken!
The question is not an idle one: I have some very small, simple modules over some noncommutative Iwasawa algebras, and I need to calculate their local cohomology quite explicitly—it is exactly a situation where I would just use the Čech complex, if the ground ring were commutative.

Your definition of "local cohomology" does not coincide with the usual one for commutative rings in general (but does under Noethetianness assumptions). See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BJA especially the warning, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0954 and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A6P

@Z.M Yes, I know. I am indeed presenting the ideas as they play out in the Noetherian case.
